# Relative layout height set to match_parent work as wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a `relative layout` which has `ScrollView` and it contain another `RelativeLayout`. Child Relative layout `layout_height` is set to `match_parent` but it react as its set to wrap_content

**Here is xml code**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.digitnomics.isite.Signage"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_signage">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Here the preview of the layout

**ScrollView set to match_parent**

[image]

**Child RelativeLayout set to match_parent**

[image]

How can I force Child Relative layout `layout_height` to fill entire height?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ScrollView set

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```